# Java AbstractTableModel repaint();

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I have a problem in my table model to update the data I print in it.

I have the class AgendaTableModel who is the table model, and the class Screen that is the main UI, when I press the button 'Listar Contatos' the table model should appear on JScrollPane in the center of the JFrame, but it continues blank.

What should be the problem ?

Comment: This doesn't make sense since table models aren't displayed -- rather JTables are. Do you mean to say that the JTable doesn't appear when you press the button? If so, then your program has a bug, but most of us aren't clairvoyant, and so I doubt anyone will know what it is without pertinent information (which should be obvious, no?). Maybe you're not calling revalidate and repaint after adding components? Maybe you're using the wrong layout manager that won't readily accept a new component? Again, without code and more information, all we can do is guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really post the code or better an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Here's the Oracle's [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) on JTable.

I'll give you some hints:

1. Each JTable has a TableModel associated
2. You don't display the TableModel but the JTable, that is a view of your model
3. When you add components dynamically you should revalidate the parent component, so if you are adding a JTable somewhere, try to revalidate its container.
4. If you are trying to add the JTable to an already existing JScrollPane (empty or containing something else), consider to instantiate a new JScrollPane rather than updating its content.

Comment: I'm dealing with some problems to post the code, asap I'll post the code.